# TextField Loading Bar like safari app {iPhone SDK}

Tags: iphone, safari

Im looking for a loading (progress bar) like the one seen in the the mobile safari app. I want a bar to cross a uitextfeild using the actual loading data. Has this been done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobileSafari is using a [private method `-setProgress:`](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UITextField), but you could simulate this using a borderless text field, and put a customized progress view beneath it.